# Suppress the_content filter in a nested loop

Tags: theme-development, loop, filters, actions, the-content

I have some layout changes that are being applied to `the_content`. I need to do one of two things, but neither is working as expected... either:

1. Pass data to the filter so that it knows if it is a "loop inside a loop" (this pertains to a special post type `events` that are outputting multiple events on a given page). The problem is that the `$post` object inside the filter is returning the `$post` for the **PAGE**, and not the specific item where the filter is about to be applied, so using `post_type` will not work.  I wonder if this is bad implementation on the part of the plugin author (calling `$post->post_content` in  a non-standard way that is preventing me from accessing it).
2. The other possibility would be to somehow detect "nested" loops, but the issue I have with this is that the main call to `the_content()` seems to be the last one firing, and I'm not sure there's a way to track number of times a loop has fired when I don't  have public access to the length of that private `wp_query()` the plugin is executing for it's own post type.

Any thoughts on something to fix this... the issue is very significant since it's trying to embed HTML layout intended only for the main page, inside the inner-loop for events.

Comment: Please include actual code, it is much easier to understand code then prose ;)

Comment: This should be possible, but the details are not clear. Are you editing a theme template, a plugin? What? And as MarkKaplun requested, include the code.